# Simplify strings with respect to substring

Tags: r, lapply, stringr

I have a db with some repeated entries that reports (inconsistently) additional information. I would like to get rid of the information and keep the most simple version for each entry.

```
db <- data.frame(company=c("ENTRY_X","ENTRY_X COUNTY_1","COUNTY_2 ENTRY_X","ENTRY_Y"))
db_desiderata <- data.frame(company=c(rep("ENTRY_X",3),"ENTRY_Y"))
```

Entries are possibly lengthy strings (some with spaces). Some examples are: "General Motors Company" and "General Motors".
I manage to isolate all the entries that need to be substituted with their substring (in db$included).
I plan to run it recursively.

Attempted code (all works, I get stuck on how to proceed):

```
db$included <- lapply(db$company, function(x) c(grep(x,db$company,value=T)))
db$lenght <- lapply(db$included, function(x) length(unlist(x)))
db$included <- ifelse(db$lenght==1,NA,db$included)
```

Answer (score 1):

The following should work if the data strictly conforms to these patterns:

1. The desired name must be the first in the sequence of alternative names
2. The desired name must be the shortest in the sequence of alternative names and can't be followed by a company name which is a shorter subset of the preceding company name.

I'll use a variation of Chuck P's data to illustrate how this works and the problems if the patterns aren't followed.

```
db <- data.frame(company = c("General Foods","More General Foods","General Foods Cereal Division","General Auto",
                         "General Motors Company", "General Motors", "European General Motors Company", 
                          "General", "Asia General Toys") )

companies <- Reduce( f = function(y,x) {if(grepl(pattern = y, x=x)) y else x},
                 x=db$company, accumulate = TRUE)
```

which gives

```
companies
[1] General Foods          General Foods          General Foods          General Auto           General Motors Company
[6] General Motors         General Motors         General                General
```

Comment: A very nice solution @WaltS!  I just couldn't let myself make too many assumptions about company names, kept thinking of all the ways it could go wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand your situation a little better after your comment but I still would be very wary of a fully automated solution,  One slip or one term that was too **general** (*pun-intended*) and you're hosed...

I've taken your early work and done a little renaming.  Think of your original `length` as more a measure of potential.  I'd look at the potential column with a human eye and pick and choose the places to replace.  I'd approach this with `stringr::str_replace_all`.  If you use the named vector as I've shown below you should be able to handle a wide array of cases with cut and paste.  `"^.*General Motors.*$"` just means if you find it anywhere in the string, front or back.  You can work iteratively and just keep adding to the named vector until you have it cleaned.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

db <- data.frame(company = c("General Foods","More General Foods","General Foods Cereal Division","General", "General Auto", "General Motors Company", "General Motors", "European General Motors Company"))

db$similar_company <- sapply(db$company, function(x) c(grep(x, db$company, value=T)), simplify = TRUE)

db$potential <- sapply(db$similar_company, function(x) length(unlist(x)), simplify = TRUE)

glimpse(db)
#> Rows: 8
#> Columns: 3
#> $ company         <chr> "General Foods", "More General Foods", "General Foods…
#> $ similar_company <named list> [<"General Foods", "More General Foods", "Gene…
#> $ potential       <int> 3, 1, 1, 8, 1, 2, 3, 1

db %>% arrange(desc(potential)) %>% select(-similar_company)
#>                           company potential
#> 1                         General         8
#> 2                   General Foods         3
#> 3                  General Motors         3
#> 4          General Motors Company         2
#> 5              More General Foods         1
#> 6   General Foods Cereal Division         1
#> 7                    General Auto         1
#> 8 European General Motors Company         1

db$newcompany <- 
  str_replace_all(db$company, c("^.*General Foods.*$" = "General Foods",
                                "^.*General Motors.*$" = "General Motors"),
  )

db %>% select(company, newcompany)
#>                           company     newcompany
#> 1                   General Foods  General Foods
#> 2              More General Foods  General Foods
#> 3   General Foods Cereal Division  General Foods
#> 4                         General        General
#> 5                    General Auto   General Auto
#> 6          General Motors Company General Motors
#> 7                  General Motors General Motors
#> 8 European General Motors Company General Motors
```

<sup>Created on 2020-05-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: The problem is that ENTRY_X is not given, and needs to be extracted for a very large dataset. In the GM example, given "General Motors","General Motors Company", and "European General Motor" company, I need to first figure out that the string to replace is "General Motor", then proceed to substitute.